# How can I make textpos respect beamer overlays?

Tags: beamer, positioning, overlays, textpos

I'm using `textpos` to position text blocks in a `beamer` frame.  However, the `textblock` environment does not seem to respect overlay commands.  In the following example, I want "some more text" to be invisible on the first slide and visible on the second.  However, when I compile the document, it is visible on both slides.  How can I make it invisible on the first slide?

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[overlay,absolute]{textpos}
\setlength{\TPHorizModule}{1cm}
\setlength{\TPVertModule}{1cm}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
Some text

  \visible<2->{
        \begin{textblock}{5}(6,6)
            Some more text
        \end{textblock}
          }
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

**Edit:** Both of the answers that have been given so far are quite useful, and I am not sure which one to accept.  On one hand, CyberSingularity's answer allows me to use multiple `textblock` environments with a single overlay command, while Paul Gaborit's answer would require a different overlay command for each `textblock`.  On the other hand, Paul Gaborit's answer allows me to use the `\visible` command.  I prefer `\visible` to `\only`, since, as cyberSingularity noted, `\visible` reserves the amount of space that it needs.

Comment: You can put your call to `\visible` into your `textblock` environment.

Comment: Thanks to [this answer}(http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/83654/13034), I'm OK with the idea of using an `\overlayarea` in combination with `\only` commands.  So, I've decided to accept @cyberSingularity's answer.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It works as expected if you use `\only` instead of `\visible`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[overlay,absolute]{textpos}
\setlength{\TPHorizModule}{1cm}
\setlength{\TPVertModule}{1cm}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
Some text

  \only<2->{
        \begin{textblock}{5}(6,6)
            Some more text
        \end{textblock}
          }
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Why does one work and not the other?

Comment: @AndrewUzzell: `\visible` takes up space on the slides where the content is not shown, whereas `\only` does not. In order to work out the amount of space that needs to be reserved, I presume that `\visible` actually typesets its argument in all cases, but just doesn't show the result. When the content has side-effects like eg `\addtocounter`, the side-effects are retained. The `textblock` environment presumably also works via a side-effect.

Comment: To add to what cyberSingularity has said, `\visible` works by changing the colour (actually, the transparency) of its text.  Presumably the `textblock` environment either ignores or overrides this (whether by accident or design).

Comment: @AndrewStacey: and when normal text is set in invisible/transparent mode, it is not selectable/searchable by PDF viewers. I think all of this could be better explained in the `beamer` manual than currently.

Answer (score 10):

It works as expected if you call `\visible` into your `textpos` environment:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[overlay,absolute]{textpos}
\setlength{\TPHorizModule}{1cm}
\setlength{\TPVertModule}{1cm}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  Some text

  \begin{textblock}{5}(6,6)
    \visible<2->{
      Some more text
    }
  \end{textblock}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: great! your solution is better, because \visible avoids jumping elements. when I used \only, elements are re-arranged when new element appears.